# Cannot cleanup ghost mount points

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, mount, unmounting

'mount' command shows several mount points across several disk devices that I had previously setup:

```
$ mount
...
/dev/sdf1 on /mnt/<mp1>  type xfs (rw)
...
/dev/sdd1 on /mnt/<mp2>  type xfs (rw)
...
```

But I cannot 'umount' any of these "ghost" mount points:

```
$ umount -f /mnt/<mp1>
mount: /mnt/<mp1>: mountpoint not found
```

I also checked the directory was removed:

```
$ ls -al /mnt
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Apr  1 14:57 .
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root root 4096 Apr  1 13:21 ..
```

I'm root user running on CentOS7 linux:

```
$ whoami
root

$ cat /etc/*release*
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
...
```

I also tried rebooting my system but those mountpoints still show up.  I cannot find any process that would still be using these mounts.  What gives??? Any other ideas about how to clean up these 'ghost' mount points?

Comment: did you try deleting them from `/etc/mtab` ?

Comment: Related, do they exist in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Tho you can't see those dirs, there may be one or more processes using them. Try if they are shown with `fuser /mnt` or `lsof /mnt`.

Comment: That above should be `lsof +D /mnt` and `fuser -m /mnt`.

Comment: I did remove them from fstab.  But had no idea about mtab file.  I removed them from there and that did the trick!  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm....I'd be surprised if a reboot would not cure this problem.

However, if you are not into reboots you can try using the lazy unmount option that Linux provides:

```
 umount -l /my-mount
```

and that remove it from visible mount table.  I've done this with success.

Comment: I get the same error as if I try umount -f /mnt/<mp1>

Answer (score 1):

Try referring to the mounted device(s) instead

```
# umount -f /dev/sdf1
```

Or, create the mount points, then unmount, then remove the mount points.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work.  As suggested above, i removed the references in /etc/mtab. That seemed to work.